# Displaying user data within ACF relational field (user type)

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, user-meta

I'm trying to display user info including custom fields determined by an ACF relational user field, and all contained within a flexible content field.

*EDIT* Updated code following answers / comments, but still can't get anything to output - all my variables are empty.

The flexible content part is fine, and I'm just including it for context.

I have hit a brick wall with getting the related user info out though.

Within my flexible content layout, I have:

**Field Type:** User
**Select multiple values?:** Yes
**Return format:** User Array

Then in my template I have (most HTML Stripped out):

(`role` and `author_image` are ACF fields in the user entry).

```
<?php
$posts = get_sub_field('who_to_show');

  if( $posts ):

    foreach( $posts as $post):

      setup_postdata($post);

      $user_info = get_userdata($post);
      $image = get_field('author_image', 'user_' . $user_info->post_author );
      $role = get_field('role', 'user_' . $user_info->post_author );
      ?>

      <p><?php echo $role; ?></p>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

    <?php endforeach;

  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I also tried:

```
<?php
$posts = get_sub_field('who_to_show');

  if( $posts ):

    foreach( $posts as $post):

      setup_postdata($post);

      $image = get_field('author_image');
      $role = get_field('role');
      ?>

      <p><?php echo $role; ?></p>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

    <?php endforeach;

  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And still my variables are empty.

It's worth noting the image field Return Value is set to "Image Array" in ACF.

Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: so basically you want to get `'author_image'` from `$user_info`, right?

Comment: I want to get info from get_userdata, as well as a custom field (text) and custom field (image). None of them work, so I have got something fundamentally wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was only slightly different from Lewis' answer:

```
<?php
  $posts = get_sub_field('who_to_show');

  if( $posts ):

    foreach( $posts as $post):

        $userdata = get_user_by('ID',$post['ID']);
        $image = get_field('author_image', 'user_'. $post['ID'] );
        $role = get_field('role', 'user_'. $post['ID'] );

        echo $userdata->first_name;
        echo $role;

    endforeach;

    endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to call `get_userdata()`, all the data you need should be in the relational field array:

**EDIT**: Add post ID and User ID to calls to `get_field()`.

```
<?php
$posts = get_sub_field('who_to_show');

    if( $posts ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $posts as $post):

            setup_postdata($post);
            $user_info = get_field( 'relational_user_field', $post->ID );
            $image = get_the_field('author_image', 'user_'.$user_info->ID );
            $role = get_the_field('role', 'user_'.$user_info->ID );
            ?>

            <h3><?php echo $user_info->user_nicename; ?></h3>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

        <?php endforeach;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif; ?>
```

Obviously swap `'relational_user_field'` for your actual field name.
The data returned in the user array is the same as the return values in [`the_author_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)

Comment: Thank you but I was using `get_userdata()` in an attempt to get the standard user information rather than ACF fields. I tried adapting your answer but my variables are empty. Question updated with my new attempts.

Comment: It looks like you're passing a Post ID to `get_userdata()` but you need to pass a User ID.

Comment: Ok, I'm taking what I can from the ACF documentation but that doesn't provide examples for the "User" field type in this context. Would you be able to update your answer / point me to some documentation that might help?

Comment: Sure thing - if you read [the ACF docs on `get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) you'll see a section called 'Get value from different objects' which explains the formatting required for getting field values from various object types. The format required for user objects is 'user_1' (where '1' is the user ID). I've updated my code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `get_the_field`, whilst the proper function to get acf data is `get_field` or `the_field` if you want to echo the stuff immediately.. i guess, this breaks your template.

not sure, if i got you right, but if you added the field `author_image` to the user, than the following answer will get you there. if not, than my answer is crap :)

the proper way of getting acf data from a user would be like this:

```
get_field('author_image', 'user_' . $user_info->post_author );
```

when you simply call `get_field('parameter')` it will return data from the current post, similar to `get_field('parameter', get_the_ID())`, so if you change that second parameter to whatever ID you have, you could get it from that specific ID.. in case of `user` it is `user_(USER_ID)`

Comment: Changing `get_the_field` to `get_field` stopped my template from breaking thank you. I still can't get any data though. I updated question with my new attempts.

Comment: @user2265915 so you created 2 acf fields `author_image` & `role` and added them to location `user form is equal to all`. then you added content to these fields in the user accounts. then you call these users inside some repeater/flexible. all correct till this point?

Comment: Yes, though I used `user role is equal to all` rather than `user form`. I call these users inside a [**relational** user] field, which is within a flexible content field.

Comment: i once had the same setting you are using, but then i switched it to the one i mentioned in my comment, since the other one was having a bug that i reported. not sure if it is fixed by now, i strongly believe it, but the answer from the dev guy was: use that setting until its fixed. this settings works for me, so there was no need for me to switch it back. please try.. change the field-settings and update the user one more time.